# Finding a volume of a region bounded by $y=x^2$, $x=1$, and $y=0$ through the use of shell method revolved about the line $y=-10$

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

I want to set up an integral that can get the volume surrounded by $y=x^2$, $x=1$, and $y=0$ revolved about the line $y=-10$.

This is what I have so far:
$$\int\limits\limits_{0}^{1} 2 \pi \ (10-y)(\sqrt{y})\ dy$$

But I have not been able to get a correct answer out of this integral.

Comment: Isn't your radius $10+y$?

Comment: Have you made a sketch of the geometrical situation?  The curve $ \ x \  = \ \sqrt{y} \ $ is the "lower boundary" for this region when it is revolved about the "horizontal" line $ \ y \ = \ -10 \ . \ $ What is the "_upper_ boundary"?

Comment: The height of the cylinder is $h=1-\sqrt{y}$ and the radius is $r=y+11$.